# Applying value of checkbox to API request URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, checkbox

I have a checkbox which, based on its checked status, will append either "subscribed" or "unsubscribed" to the end of a request URL. The issue is that I can't get it to apply to the end of the URL.

```
<form role="form" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group selectors">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 portfolio-item">
    <h5>Region</h5>
          <select class="form-control" name="region" id="region" >

                     <option value="US" selected="selected">US</option>
                     <option value="UK">UK</option>
                     <option value="XS">XS</option>
                     <option value="XT">XT</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 portfolio-item">
      <h5>Duration</h5>
          <select class="form-control" name="duration" id="duration" >

                     <option value="5" selected="selected">5 Minutes</option>
                     <option value="10">10 Minutes</option>
                     <option value="15">15 Minutes</option>
                     <option value="20">20 Minutes</option>
                     <option value="25">25 Minutes</option>
                     <option value="30">30 Minutes</option>
          </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="status" name="status" />
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

`

`<input type="checkbox" id="status" name="status" />`

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
var status = input.checked ? "subscribed" : "unsubscribed";
```

request url:

```
dataStore({
   callback:callback,
   cacheExp: 0,
   apiUrl: "region/"+ (options.req.query.region ? options.req.query.region : "US") + "/duration/" + (options.req.query.duration ? options.req.query.duration : "5")
});
```

I need to add `"?subscribed=" + status` to the end of the request url, but it is breaking my code.

The end results should look like this: `region/US/duration/15?subscribed=true`

When I apply the checkbox status to the end of the url like so:

`"region/"+ (options.req.query.region ? options.req.query.region : "US") + "/duration/" + (options.req.query.duration ? options.req.query.duration : "5") + "?subscribed=" + status`

I get `ReferenceError: status is not defined` in the terminal.

Comment: why is it breaking your code? what EXACTLY is the problem?

Comment: Check my update to the description.

Comment: I think you can use `options.req.query.region || "US"` instead of `options.req.query.region ? options.req.query.region : "US"`

Comment: Is everything in the same context? What does it output when you try to access (e.g. `console.log`) `input`?

Comment: Read [ask]. Create MCVE.

Comment: Aside from simplifying the query, I just need to figure out what is wrong with my syntax in trying to append `"?subscribed=" + status` to the end of the apiURL.

Comment: Here's what's wrong with your code: `status` is failing at being defined. You gotta find why. Is anything being set to `input` or is it not being defined as well?

Comment: Also, here is a [great definition of MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in case you don't know it (I didn't). Your example code is neither Complete nor Verifiable.

Comment: I can't include all the code, nor can I supply a fiddle, since its a node app. I'm merely asking how to include the value of a variable from a checked box to the end of the url as a parameter.

Comment: I see. Is this code in a template file, or is it in a backend Javascript file? i.e. is this code inside HTML? Your backend files won't have direct access to `DOM` elements.

Comment: I have added my form code to the question. I am able to grab the selected options from those drop-downs, but can't get the value from the checkbox. Hopefully this clears up the issue.

Comment: I have found that it works if I use a dropdown to set the subscribed status, instead of a checkbox(as originally desired), and appending `+ "?subscribed=" + (options.req.query.subscribed)` to the end of the api url.